# Force a process in the kernel to sleep for 60 seconds

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Say I have a "bad" process in the kernel which I want to punish by forcing it to sleep for exactly a 60 seconds and then reschedule it -- How do I do it? What are the functions and data structures in the kernel that I have to manipulate to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in that process's context, and does not hold any locks, just do a msleep / ssleep.

```
 ssleep(60);
```

Note, this will not be "exactly" 60 sec, just as accurate as the `sleep()` function goes.

If you are in other process's context, you need to suspend that process a signal and schedule a wake. I guess that would be simplier with a usermode helper process. See [this for how to invoke a helper](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#s7).

Comment: Hmm, I am doing this in Kernel mode so I can't use user mode fucntions. I am basically modifying the scheduling mechanism.

Comment: arruuug. Is this a homework or something? Modifying the scheduler is prone to error and will surely break on upgrade.

Comment: this is a part of a little project I have. the details are more complex, but I can't find a good way in the kernel to literally punish a bad task for a predetermined time.

Comment: So... what do you consider a 'bad' task in the kernel anyway? Nothing in the kernel is supposed to do anything for any length of time: I don't see how you would need to suspend a process for one minute...